# Why do I get NPE when I invoke android.content.Context.getApplicationContext() within Application's constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-context, applicationcontext

My Application class looks something similar to this,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Context mContext;

    public MyApplication() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside my application.. " + this);
        Log.i(TAG, "Value of application context is  : " + this.getApplicationContext());
        mContext = this;
    }
}
```

I get NPE and my app is crashing when I do something like above,

```
12-15 12:03:57.886  8174  8174 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.gm, PID: 8174
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.gm.MyApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1087)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5905)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:207)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1660)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6734)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:116)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.gm.MyApplication.<init>(MyApplication.java:12)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:49)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1079)
12-15 12:03:57.890  8174  8174 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
```

Whereas in plain java code for a class which looks something like this,

```
public class Student {
    int age;
    String name;
    String badgeid;

    public Student(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.badgeid = this.age + this.name;
    }
}
```

does not cause NPE when I do `this.age` and `this.name`. How do the above application snippet is something different than the below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do the above application snippet is something different than the below?

`Student` has no superclass (other than `Object`, the default). You are referencing fields that you defined yourself on `Student`.

`Application` has superclasses, as you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application). So, let's add a superclass to your `Student`:

```
public class Base {
  String something;

  public void onCreate() {
    something = "a value";
  }
}

public class Student extends Base {
    int age;
    String name;
    String badgeid;
    int value;

    public Student(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.badgeid = this.age + this.name;
        this.value = something.length;
    }
}
```

Here, you will crash with a `NullPointerException`, because `something` is `null` at the time that you try calling `something.length`. The superclass does not set `something` to a value until `onCreate()` is called. You are referencing `something` too early.

Similarly, you cannot call methods exposed by `Context` until the appropriate time. In the case of `Application`, `Activity`, and `Service`, that is after your `onCreate()` calls `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: As always, you are awesome !

Comment: How the call is delegated here in the case of application? In case of activity I would generally call `super.onCreate()` at the end. If I left my application as it is in the example, will the compiler auto generate remaining methods to call `super.onCreate` and others? How this lifecycle methods getting invoked?

Comment: @rm-rfstar: "In case of activity I would generally call super.onCreate() at the end" -- I think pretty much everyone recommends calling it first. "If I left my application as it is in the example, will the compiler auto generate remaining methods to call super.onCreate and others?" -- the framework is calling `onCreate()`, not the compiler.

Comment: How framework invokes each lifecycle method without someone invoking it?

Comment: @rm-rfstar: The framework *is* "someone". It is code, written by Google. It is part of your process. It orchestrates all the operations of your components (`Application`, activities, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this in onCreate() method, it should work because you are doing this in constructor may be the issue due to that.